# Is there a way to overwrite the default pattern for ToString() for LocalDate?

Tags: c#, nodatime

A common pattern in my code is using a LocalDate (or other NodaTime type) from string interpolation when generating message text. By default, this ends up using the default format pattern ("D") which is localized.

Is there a way to overwrite the default pattern used by ToString() for LocalDate? I would like to always format using an ISO pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the current culture to one with the formats you want in its [DateTimeFormatInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo). But that's all - there's no other mechanism provided by Noda Time, just like there's no other mechanism provided by the BCL.

I'd encourage you just to be explicit instead - ideally using `LocalDatePattern`.

Answer (score -2):

The answer to your question is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

It states the ISO format you are looking for as well

Comment: I am looking for a global setting - I don't want to find and then modify all occurrences of localDate in $ to pass a custom pattern.